# How to concat two JSONObject with same key of a JSONArray in flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

The JSON request has been split into two json object in the DataList JSONArray , because data is too large, how do i combine these two objects before i can decompress and get the values . Iam new to dart and flutter , any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
 "DataList": [
                    {
                        "Data": "compressedata"
                    },
                    {
                        "Data": "compressedData"
                    }
                ],
```

here is what i have tried

```
class ResponseList {
 
 List<DataList> dataList;
 
 ResponseList({ this.DataList});

 ResponseList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  if (json['DataList'] != null) {
   DataList = new List<DataList>();
    json['DataList'].forEach((v) {
    dataList.add(new DataList.fromJson(v));
    });
  }
  
 }

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.DataList != null) {
    map['DataList'] = this.dataList.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
  }
  
  return map;
 }
}
class DataList {
 String data;
 DataList({this.data});
 DataList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  data = json['Data'];

 }

 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
  final Map<String, dynamic> map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
  map['Data'] = this.data;
  return map;
 }
}
```

Comment: How would you like the combined data to look? 
Do you want it to be concatanated like: 
`Data = "compressedDatacompressedData"`

Comment: @ChadLamb Yes , concat because i need to decompress the combined string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Datalist array you can do the following:

```
 var dataList = [
    {"Data": "compressedata"},
    {"Data": "compressedData"}
  ];

  var compressedData = dataList
      .map((item) => item["Data"])
      .reduce((value, element) => value + element);

  print(compressedData); // compressedatacompressedData
```